# How we can return dataset to Iphone app by using WCF

Tags: iphone, wcf

I am new to wcf.

i am working on WCF service which will be consume by IPhone application.In this service i have to return Dataset in some methods.So i want to know here which technique i have to use for implement this.If possible please provide me some example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a **lot** of work. You will have to decode the XML (via NSXMLParser) and construct the data set's contents yourself.

If at all possible, modify the server to return a simpler data representation.